# This code for creating a QPolygon in Pyqt is stopping my application! Help?

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

HI all,

The following code:

```
self.painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
self.painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
self.painter.translate(482,395)
self.painter.scale(300,300)
self.painter.save()
needle = Qt.QPolygon([QPoint(30, 0), QPoint(-30, 0), QPoint(0, 200)])
self.painter.setBrush(Qt.cyan)
self.painter.setPen(Qt.black)
self.painter.drawPolygon(needle)
self.painter.restore()
```

is causing my Pyqt application to crash. Does anyone have any idea why? It is part of my ui_form.py file which was automatically spat out by pyuic4. Removing / commenting it out fixes the problem. Yes, I wrote this myself instead of the compiler doing it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried saving the painter before translating it and scaling it ? (or even before changing the renderhint) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the list which you pass the the constructor of `QPolygon` in a local variable. I guess that the elements get garbage collected as soon as the call returns so when you draw the polygon, they are no longer around.

```
points = [QPoint(30, 0), QPoint(-30, 0), QPoint(0, 200)]
needle = Qt.QPolygon(points)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aaron, unfortunately even after making that change I am getting the error:

Comment: TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QPainter(): too many arguments
  QPainter(QPaintDevice): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Dash'

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not creating your QPolygon correctly.

```
QPolygon ()
    QPolygon ( int size )
    QPolygon ( const QPolygon & polygon )
    QPolygon ( const QVector & points )
    QPolygon ( const QRect & rectangle, bool closed = false )
```

You can create a polygon with on integer, an already created QPolygon, a QVector, or a QRect which also passes true or false to close the polygon.

Comment: Also, you have QPolygon from QtCore.Qt ... since when is the QPolygon a part of the QtCore.Qt libraries? It's a part of QtGui in 4.6. I am surprise that does not fail.